# Headings from scratch: How to add "smart" vertical space?

Tags: sectioning

I'm trying to create my own sectioning commands from scratch. While I'm able to break lines wherever, I don't know how to add padding to my headings and spacing between my subexercises. I've tried using `\bigskip` or `\vskip`, but it results in too much space when one sectioning command directly follows another. `\section`, `\subsection`, etc. are able to merge successive spacing. Is there a simple way to replicate this behavior?

**Edit**: I've made progress by using `\addvspace`. It looks good to my eye, except that the space between an `\exercise` and a `\subexercise` immediately following it looks wrong. See for example the space between exercise 1 and subexercise (A). I would prefer if the larger `\addvspace` from `\subexercise` was ignored in this case.

Here is what I have so far:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{stix2}

\NewDocumentCommand\exercise{m}{
  \par
  % VERTICAL SPACING BEFORE HEADING
    \addvspace{\baselineskip}
  %
  \noindent
  {\bfseries\Large Exercise #1}
  \par
  % VERTICAL SPACING AFTER HEADING
    \addvspace{0.25\baselineskip}
  %
  \noindent
  \ignorespaces
}
\NewDocumentCommand\subexercise{m}{
  \par
  % VERTICAL SPACING BETWEEN SUBEXERCISES
    \addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}
  %
  \noindent
  \makebox[0pt][r]{(#1)\hspace\labelsep}%
  \ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}
\exercise{1}
\subexercise{A}
Aliquam ornare viverra nunc.
Pellentesque et velit nulla.
Integer vestibulum nisi auctor justo malesuada, id facilisis tortor finibus.
\subexercise{B}
Maecenas sem turpis, congue vel cursus ac, ultricies vel ligula.
Sed rutrum blandit luctus.
\exercise{2}
Morbi risus dui, aliquet non vulputate ut, pulvinar nec velit.
Proin venenatis leo nibh, vel malesuada eros tempus sit amet.
Duis semper elit sit amet lectus luctus ultricies.
\subexercise{A}
Cras euismod est diam, eu iaculis quam euismod vel.
Vivamus facilisis nec nisi non gravida.
Etiam ipsum erat, tristique sit amet ante non, porta iaculis odio.
Pellentesque varius purus vel nisl pellentesque imperdiet at a leo.
\[
  E = mc^2
\]
\subexercise{B}
Proin sed posuere nulla, sit amet imperdiet turpis.
Nam dictum tempus dictum.
Maecenas at rutrum nibh, vitae maximus magna.
Nulla et ante eu diam pretium facilisis.
\exercise{3}
\exercise{4}
\end{document}
```

[image: PDF output]

Comment: there is a bit more involved in headings that simply the spacing. You also need to suppress pagebreaks after the heading, and perhaps you need references and links. Consider to use \@startsection to define your command, or a least study the default definition.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look. I don't need most of the fancy features of a normal section command, except perhaps keeping the heading together with the next paragraph. I've updated my question with the progress I've made so far. `\addvspace` does almost exactly what I want, except that I get too much space in one case.

Comment: well what you call "fancy" is the code needed to solve the problems in your question. There is for example code to suppress spacing between a section and subsection.

Comment: I see that now. Your suggestion worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, headings are not that simple to implement properly. Fortunately, the built-in `\@startsection` command is flexible enough to implement the desired layout, although it is a bit hard to use.

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 10pt]{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{stix2}
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand\exercise{m}{
\@startsection{}{1}{0mm}
  {-\baselineskip} % before
  {0.25\baselineskip} % after
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}*
  {Exercise #1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand\subexercise{m}{
\@startsection{}{2}{0mm}
  {0.5\baselineskip} % before
  {0mm} % after
  {}*
  {\makebox[0pt][r]{(#1)\hspace\labelsep}}
}

\makeatother


\begin{document}
\exercise{1}
\subexercise{A}
Aliquam ornare viverra nunc.
Pellentesque et velit nulla.
Integer vestibulum nisi auctor justo malesuada, id facilisis tortor finibus.
\subexercise{B}
Maecenas sem turpis, congue vel cursus ac, ultricies vel ligula.
Sed rutrum blandit luctus.
\exercise{2}
Morbi risus dui, aliquet non vulputate ut, pulvinar nec velit.
Proin venenatis leo nibh, vel malesuada eros tempus sit amet.
Duis semper elit sit amet lectus luctus ultricies.
\subexercise{A}
Cras euismod est diam, eu iaculis quam euismod vel.
Vivamus facilisis nec nisi non gravida.
Etiam ipsum erat, tristique sit amet ante non, porta iaculis odio.
Pellentesque varius purus vel nisl pellentesque imperdiet at a leo.
\[
  E = mc^2
\]
\subexercise{B}
Proin sed posuere nulla, sit amet imperdiet turpis.
Nam dictum tempus dictum.
Maecenas at rutrum nibh, vitae maximus magna.
Nulla et ante eu diam pretium facilisis.
\exercise{3}
\exercise{4}
\end{document}
```

[image]